# Angular mssql Connection

Tags: angular, node-mssql

why this is happening, is there any solutions?

./src/polyfills.ts:53:0-14 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
- install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js:3:16-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/js-md4/src/md4.js:132:17-34 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\js-md4\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

./node_modules/mssql/lib/base/request.js:11:4-21 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\mssql\lib\base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/native-duplexpair/index.js:3:15-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\native-duplexpair'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/tarn/dist/Pool.js:15:17-34 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tarn\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify") }'
- install 'timers-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "timers": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/bulk-load.js:12:14-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:12:37-54 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:14:33-46 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
- install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:16:34-48 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:18:40-60 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "constants": require.resolve("constants-browserify") }'
- install 'constants-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "constants": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:20:14-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js:12:34-48 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

./node_modules/tedious/lib/debug.js:10:35-50 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
- install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/incoming-message-stream.js:10:14-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js:11:34-48 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

./node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js:14:34-48 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

./node_modules/tedious/lib/message.js:8:14-31 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modules\tedious\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

./node_modules/tedious/lib/ntlm-payload.js:10:37-54 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\development\development_repo\sw-pharmacy\node_modulcy\node_modules\tedious\lib\token'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }